# nested generics in swift 3

Tags: swift, generics

is it possible to do following in Swift 3 with generics ?

```
class BaseModel {} 
class Human : BaseModel {
var name = ""
}

class BaseService<T: BaseVM<BaseModel>> {
   //init viewmodel with generic model
}

class BaseVM<T: BaseModel> {}

class HumanVM: BaseVM<Human> {
var name = ""
init(model : Human) {
    super.init()
    name = model.name
  }
}

class HumanService: BaseService<HumanVM> {}
```

what I am trying to do is initializing viewModel with generic model in baseService.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can nest generics.  The problem with what you have is this line:

```
class BaseService<T: BaseVM<BaseModel>> { ...
```

Here you've said `BaseService` must be initialized with a type that inherits from `BaseVM` whose generic **IS** `BaseModel`.  If you want `BaseService` to be able to take a type that inherits from `BaseVM` whose model inherits from `BaseModel`, you'd have to do it this way:

```
class BaseService<T: BaseModel, U: BaseVM<T>> { ...
```

Here is a version of what you have above that compiles:

```
class BaseModel {}

class BaseVM<T: BaseModel> {}

class BaseService<T: BaseModel, U: BaseVM<T>> {
    //init viewmodel with generic model
}

class Human : BaseModel {
    var name = ""
}

class HumanVM: BaseVM<Human> {
    var name = ""
    init(model : Human) {
        super.init()
        name = model.name
    }
}

class HumanService: BaseService<Human, HumanVM> {}
```

An alternate approach to describing these relationships would be to use [Protocols with AssociatedTypes](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-protocols-with-associated-types/).  Your code would look something like this:

```
protocol Model {}

protocol BaseVM {
    associatedtype VMModel : Model
}

protocol BaseService {
    associatedtype ServiceVM : BaseVM
}

class Human : Model {
    var name = ""
}

class HumanVM : BaseVM {
    typealias VMModel = Human
}

class HumanService : BaseService {
    typealias ServiceVM = HumanVM
}
```

Without knowing more about what problem you're trying to solve, I can't say which is more appropriate.

**EDIT** I'm still not totally clear how this is applicable to the MVVM pattern, but probably, if views are involved, you'd want a `Protocol`-based solution so that you could make `UIView` conform to it.

Comment: Actually I am trying to apply MVVM pattern, I want to encapsulate model object, BaseService responsible from requesting to server and converting response to related model and initialize related view model with model object,

Comment: See my edits.  I added some more details relevant to the specific question.   I think a `Protocol` approach would probably be a more natural fit.