# Swift 3 Nested Generic Compiler Crash

Tags: swift, crash

I found this link ([nested generics in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654471/nested-generics-in-swift-3)) that solved one of my problems but now the problem is when I try to Inherit from a UIView (in this case) using nested generics the compiler crash.

```
class BaseModel {}

class BaseVM<T: BaseModel> {}

class BaseService<T: BaseModel, U: BaseVM<T>> : UIView {
   //init viewmodel with generic model
}

class Human : BaseModel {
   var name = ""
}

class HumanVM: BaseVM<Human> {
   var name = ""
   init(model : Human) {
      super.init()
      name = model.name
   }
}

class HumanService: BaseService<Human, HumanVM> {}
```

This specific pice of code `: UIView` make the compiler crash.
Is it a limitation? or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT: It works on Swift 3.1 beta.

Comment: Whatever input you give it, a compiler should not crash. So you should report a bug, whether or not the program you wrote is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works on Swift 3.1 beta

Then use Swift 3.1 beta (Xcode 8.3). It [introduces](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8.3_beta_5.pdf) a lot of new nested generic features and fixes many compiler bugs having to do with generics.